# How to get accurate solutions from FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

I am a new user in Wolfram language.

Please, I am trying to calculate accurate solutions $R$ of an algébric equation which contains the Dawson function. The equation is:

$$1+\frac{\theta }{k^2}+\frac{R^2}{k^2}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\theta }} \left(\frac{1}{2} \theta ^2 \left(\frac{R^2}{2}+1\right)^2+\theta  \left(\frac{R^2}{2}+1\right)+1\right) \left(-2 F\left(\sqrt{\frac{\theta }{2}} R\right)\right)}{R}+1+\theta  \left(\frac{1}{4 \theta }+\frac{R^2}{4}+1\right)\right]=0$$

where,

$F$ :  is the Dawson function

$1<k<3$ : real

$R<1$ : real

$\theta \ggg 1$ : real >>1

To do it, I think we have to use Findroot. The code that I used is the following:

```
eq[R_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ]:=1+\[Theta]/k^2+R^2/k^2 (1+\[Theta](1+1/(4\[Theta])+R^2/4)+(Sqrt[2/\[Theta]] 1/R (1+\[Theta](1+(R^2)/2)+\[Theta]^2/2 (1+(R^2)/2)^2)(-2 DawsonF[Sqrt[\[Theta]/2]R])))

solr[k_,\[Theta]_]:=Re[R/.FindRoot[eq[R,k,\[Theta]],{R,1.1/k},AccuracyGoal->16,PrecisionGoal->16,WorkingPrecision->25]]
```

The solutions $R$ that I'm looking for must satisfy: *for all values $1<k<3$ we have always $R<1$*.

But for $k<2.1$ all solutions satisfy $R>>1$, so the condition $R<1$ is not satisfied.

```
Block[{\[Theta]=100},Table[{k,solr[k,\[Theta]]},{k,1,3,0.1}]]
 (* {{1.,-402.0221127442610480453402},{1.1,162.7992531392247315125129},{1.2,560.0440880401854997217024},{1.3,149.3137124001590352102585}, {1.4,927.9240354439233066791802},{1.5,1204.227451826562972959649},{1.6,  352.3919638872815653450775},{1.7,-578.9018078239970096174140},{1.8,2.284779688985257597042901},{1.9,1.366209370422262795909812},{2.,1.059718464650025788056352},{2.1,0.8928149869232555556054552},{2.2,0.7840644848720738071277466},{2.3,0.7061209842390898952755792},{2.4,0.6468555823332280593457180},{2.5,0.5999539682600659528508929},{2.6,0.5617652337478441609444316},{2.7,0.5300143374213611634335440},{2.8,0.5031957080178527133949467},{2.9,0.4802563992569976549295289},{3.,0.4604211571053869996277583}} *)
```

I think this is due to the precision that I can't control.

Any help please on this problem!

Comment: Try plotting the left side of your equation for some sample parameters to see where its zeros actually are.  Also, although it may not matter, do not include `\[ThinSpace]` in your code.  It is a formatting quantity.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Of course. Thank you.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, have you please a suggestion about a solution using `Findroot`?

Comment: What improvements on the solutions below are you seeking?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Is there a way to get solutions with `FindRoot` by checking `R<1`. So according to @Mariusz this is not possible. Please, what is the best solution between the two checking `R<1`. For example, for θ = 100 at k=3 we obtain `{0.1400583759402635089617742, 0.4604211571053870525255899}`.

Comment: `FindRoot[eq[R, k, θ], {R, 1/2, 0, 1}] ` will not give roots outside `0 < R < 1`, but it will quit if its search reaches either end-point, returning the value of that end-point.  So, I do not view this as much of an improvement.  Instead, use (for instance)  `R /. FindInstance[(eq1 /. {k -> 3,  θ-> 100}) == 0 && 0 < R < 1, {R}, 5] // N`, as suggested by @Mariusz.  There is no answer to your comment of which of the two solutions is better.  Both are valid and can be found by `FindRoot` too, although with more effort.

Comment: `Reduce[(eq1 /. {k -> 3, θ -> 100}) == 0 && 0 < R < 1, {R}] // N` also works and may use the same algorithm in this case.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, very nice, thank you so much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
eq = 1 + θ/k^2 + (R (5 R + 4 R θ + R^3 θ - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/θ] (8 + 
4 (2 + R^2) θ + (2 + R^2)^2 θ^2) DawsonF[(R Sqrt[θ])/Sqrt[2]]))/(4 k^2);

n = 5;(*Increase the value to find more solution*)


FindInstance[eq == 0 && 1 < k < 3 && 0 < R < 1 && 1 < θ < 1000,
{R, k, θ}, n, RandomSeeding -> Automatic] // N // MatrixForm
```

[image]

For: `n=15`

```
n = 15;
FindInstance[
eq == 0 && 1 < k < 3 && 0 < R < 1 && 1 < θ < 1000, {R, 
k, θ}, n, RandomSeeding -> Automatic, 
WorkingPrecision -> 20] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[(eq /. θ -> j) == 0, {j, 1, 1000, 50}], {k, 1, 
3}, {R, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[(eq /. θ -> j) == 0, {j, 1, 100}], {k, 1, 
3}, {R, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

OP request: Solution by `FindRoot` (borrowed code form user: `Henrik`):

```
  Block[{R, k, \[Theta]}, 
  eq = {R, k, \[Theta]} \[Function] 
  Evaluate@
  Simplify[
  1 + \[Theta]/k^2 + 
   R^2/k^2 (1 + \[Theta] (1 + 1/(4 \[Theta]) + R^2/4) + (Sqrt[
         2/\[Theta]] 1/
         R (1 + \[Theta] (1 + (R^2)/2) + \[Theta]^2/
            2 (1 + (R^2)/2)^2) (-2 DawsonF[
           Sqrt[\[Theta]/2] R]))), \[Theta] > 0];]
     solr = {k, \[Theta]} \[Function] 
 Block[{R}, R /. FindRoot[eq[R, k, \[Theta]], {R, 1/10, 3/4}, Method -> "Secant"]] // Quiet;
 data = Block[{\[Theta] = 10}, Table[{k, solr[k, \[Theta]]}, {k, 1, 3, 1/10}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

As you can see values for `R` is not in domain: `0<R<1`.

Comment: Thanks Mariusz. Please how to plot $R$ vs $k$ for any $θ$ in your case ?

Comment: Mariusz, thank you so much.

Comment: @Gallagher. You're welcome! `:)`

Comment: So **FindRoot** doesn't give exact results of this equation?

Comment: @Gallagher. `FindRoot`in yours case is unsuitable for your calculations(
inadequate function) to solve. For example we can't add assumption like this `0<R<1`.

Comment: Ok Mariusz, I am very grateful to you.

Comment: @Gallagher.See I edit my answer.

Comment: Very great @Mariusz and @Henrik . Thank you again for your great analysis.`:) :)`

Answer (score 6):

The division by `R` in the function `eq` is superfluous and makes problems in the root finding. Fortunately, some simplification can get you rid of that:

```
Block[{R, k, θ},
 eq = {R, k, θ} \[Function] Evaluate@Simplify[ 
      1 + θ/k^2 + R^2/k^2 (1 + θ (1 + 1/(4 θ) + R^2/4) + (Sqrt[ 2/θ] 1/ R (1 + θ (1 + (R^2)/2) + θ^2/ 2 (1 + (R^2)/2)^2) (-2 DawsonF[ Sqrt[θ/2] R]))),
      θ > 0
      ];
 ]
```

Second issue: For some parameter values of `k`, there may be more than one solution or no solutions at all. `NSolve` can find (hopefully) all solution:

```
solr = {k, θ} \[Function] Block[{R}, R /. NSolve[eq[R, k, θ] == 0 && 0 <= R <= 1, R, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 25]]; 
data = Block[{θ = 100}, Table[{k, solr[k, θ]}, {k, 1, 3, 1/10}]]
ListPlot[Join @@ Thread /@ data, AxesLabel -> {"k", "R"}]
```

> {{1, {0.1294234646803674672924767}}, {11/10, {0.1296843073043101973816057}}, {6/5, {0.1299709530763769620463354}}, {13/10, {0.1302836799112623098323127}}, {7/5, {0.1306227971663856528622202}}, {3/2, {0.1309886477076770723646643}}, {8/5, {0.1313816102517342127410522}}, {17/10, {0.1318021020175089797099938}}, {9/5, {0.1322505817265513300747067}}, {19/10, {0.1327275529978164798164777}}, {2,{0.1332335681913876276756329}}, {21/
>     10, {0.1337692327655012292943036, 0.8928149869232539863495161}}, {11/5, {0.1343352102233942222258231, 0.7840644848720745156904206}}, {23/10, {0.1349322277412426656153432, 0.7061209842390900229330888}}, {12/5, {0.1355610825864964635669894, 0.6468555823332288287855214}}, {5/2, {0.1362226494580973891652682, 0.5999539682600664300172137}}, {13/5, {0.1369178889075194101436787, 0.5617652337478442737838912}}, {27/10, {0.1376478570337623102004883, 0.5300143374213614722559567}}, {14/5, {0.1384137166883060426333669, 0.5031957080178530201387233}}, {29/10, {0.1392167504801858849697920, 0.4802563992569981158981134}}, {3, {0.1400583759402635089617742, 0.4604211571053870525255899}}}

[image]

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Please how to plot $R$ vs $k$ for any $θ$?

Comment: Henrik, thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome!